# Humble Video take snapshot of given time

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg

1. Hello, I'm using https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video to take a thumbnail from a video.
   So far I have successfully managed to take a snapshot from a video at start with following method.

   ```
   private static Path generateThumbnail(final Path videoFile)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    final Demuxer demuxer = Demuxer.make();
    demuxer.open(videoFile.toString(), null, false, true, null, null);

    int streamIndex = -1;
    Decoder videoDecoder = null;
    String rotate = null;
    final int numStreams = demuxer.getNumStreams();
    for (int i = 0; i < numStreams; ++i) {
        final DemuxerStream stream = demuxer.getStream(i);
        final KeyValueBag metaData = stream.getMetaData();
        final Decoder decoder = stream.getDecoder();
        if (decoder != null
                && decoder.getCodecType() == MediaDescriptor.Type.MEDIA_VIDEO) {
            videoDecoder = decoder;
            streamIndex = i;
            rotate = metaData.getValue("rotate", KeyValueBag.Flags.KVB_NONE);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (videoDecoder == null) {
        throw new IOException("Not a valid video file");
    }
    videoDecoder.open(null, null);

    final MediaPicture picture = MediaPicture.make(videoDecoder.getWidth(),
            videoDecoder.getHeight(), videoDecoder.getPixelFormat());

    final MediaPictureConverter converter = MediaPictureConverterFactory
            .createConverter(MediaPictureConverterFactory.HUMBLE_BGR_24, picture);

    final MediaPacket packet = MediaPacket.make();
    BufferedImage image = null;
    MUX : while (demuxer.read(packet) >= 0) {
        if (packet.getStreamIndex() != streamIndex) {
            continue;
        }
        int offset = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        videoDecoder.decodeVideo(picture, packet, offset);
        do {
            bytesRead += videoDecoder.decode(picture, packet, offset);
            if (picture.isComplete()) {
                image = converter.toImage(null, picture);
                break MUX;
            }
            offset += bytesRead;

        } while (offset < packet.getSize());
    }
    if (image == null) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to find a complete video frame");
    }
    if (rotate != null) {
        final AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.translate(0.5 * image.getHeight(), 0.5 * image.getWidth());
        transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(Double.parseDouble(rotate)));
        transform.translate(-0.5 * image.getWidth(), -0.5 * image.getHeight());
        final AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform,
                AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        image = op.filter(image, null);
    }

    final Path target = videoFile.getParent()
            .resolve(videoFile.getFileName() + ".thumb.jpg");

    final double mul;
    if (image.getWidth() > image.getHeight()) {
        mul = 216 / (double) image.getWidth();
    } else {
        mul = 216 / (double) image.getHeight();
    }

    final int newW = (int) (image.getWidth() * mul);
    final int newH = (int) (image.getHeight() * mul);
    final Image thumbnailImage = image.getScaledInstance(newW, newH,
            Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    image = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);

    final Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(thumbnailImage, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();

    ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", target.toFile());
    return target.toAbsolutePath(); }
   ```
2. Now, what I want to do is take a snapshot after 2 seconds after the video starts, is it possible? I
   have tried using the "Demuxer" -s seek method but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully made it with the following code

The method from the library

```
public int seek(int stream_index, long min_ts, long ts, long max_ts, int flags);
```

Parameters are

- **stream_index** index of the stream which is used as time base reference
- **min_ts** smallest acceptable timestamp
- **ts** target timestamp
- **max_ts** largest acceptable timestamp

My Implementation was

```
final int success = demuxer.seek(streamIndex, 0, 700, 99999999,VideoJNI.Demuxer_SEEK_FRAME_get());
```